# Excel rename duplicated worksheet

Tags: excel, rename, office-scripts

I have this script
I just want to copy List1 and rename as a current date (in czech version formula '= DNES()') '=TODAY()'

```js
       function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
            let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
            // Set range B1 on selectedSheet
            selectedSheet.getRange("B1").setFormulaLocal("=DNES()");
            let list1 = workbook.getWorksheet("List1");
            let list2 = workbook.getWorksheet("List2");
            let name = list2.getRange("B1").getValue() as string;
        
            // Duplicate worksheet
            let list12 = list1.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType.before, list1);
            // Rename worksheet 
            list12.setName(name);}
```

But it seems that copied lis12 doesnt exist.

Could you please help me to rename a new copied list.

Comment: This is not VBA, it's Office Script. Please attach the correct tag, or change your code to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `selectedSheet` (ActiveSheet) may not be sheet `List2`, then `name` is empty.
- Get `name` with `getText`, otherwise it does not work on `setName(name)`

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let list1 = workbook.getWorksheet("List1");
    let list2 = workbook.getWorksheet("List2");
    list2.getRange("B1").setFormulaLocal("=TODAY()");
    let name = list2.getRange("B1").getText();
    // Duplicate worksheet
    let list12 = list1.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType.before, list1);
    // Rename worksheet 
    list12.setName(name);
}
```

- If the value in `B1` on the `List2` sheet is a temporary result representing a new sheet name, you can easily retrieve it using a User-Defined Function (UDF).
- Date format is `yyyymmdd`, modify as needed

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let list1 = workbook.getWorksheet("List1");
    // Duplicate worksheet
    let list12 = list1.copy(ExcelScript.WorksheetPositionType.before, list1);
    // Rename worksheet 
    list12.setName(getToday());
}

function getToday(){
    let today = new Date();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let day = today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let formattedDate = `${year}${month}${day}`;
    return formattedDate;
}
```